# Randomly Generating Combinations From Variable Weights

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, algorithms

## The Question

I have a list *A* of *n* ***unique*** objects.  Each object *A<sub>i</sub>* has a variable percentage *P<sub>i</sub>*.

I want to create an algorithm that generates a new list *B* of *k* objects (*k* <  <sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>2</sub> and in most cases *k* is significantly less than <sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>2</sub>.  *E.g. n=231 , k=21*).  List *B* should have no duplicates and will be populated with objects originating from list *A* with the following restriction:

> The probability that an object *A<sub>i</sub>* appears in *B* is *P<sub>i</sub>*.

## What I Have Tried

(These snippits are in PHP simply for the purposes of testing.  Your answers don't need to have code just an algorithm)
I first made list *A*

```
$list = [
    "A" => 2.5, 
    "B" => 2.5, 
    "C" => 2.5, 
    "D" => 2.5, 
    "E" => 2.5, 
    "F" => 2.5, 
    "G" => 2.5, 
    "H" => 2.5, 
    "I" => 5,   
    "J" => 5,   
    "K" => 2.5, 
    "L" => 2.5, 
    "M" => 2.5, 
    "N" => 2.5, 
    "O" => 2.5, 
    "P" => 2.5, 
    "Q" => 2.5, 
    "R" => 2.5, 
    "S" => 2.5, 
    "T" => 2.5, 
    "U" => 5,   
    "V" => 5,   
    "W" => 5,   
    "X" => 5,   
    "Y" => 5,   
    "Z" => 20   
];
```

At first I tried the following two algorthms (These are in PHP simply for the purposes of testing):

```
$result = [];

while (count($result) < 10) {
  $rnd = rand(0,10000000) / 100000;

    $sum = 0;
  foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $sum += $value;
        if ($rnd <= $sum) {
            if (in_array($key,$result)) {
                break;
            } else {
                $result[] = $key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
$result = [];

while (count($result) < 10) {
     $sum = 0;
     foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
      $sum += $value;
    }

    $rnd = rand(0,$sum * 100000) / 100000;

    $sum = 0;
     foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $sum += $value;
        if ($rnd <= $sum) {
            $result[] = $key;
            unset($list[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The only differences between the two algorithms is that one tries again when it encounters a duplicate, and one removes the object form list *A* when it is picked.  As it turns out, these two algorithms have the same probability outputs.

I ran the second algorithm 100,000 times and kept track of how many times each letter was picked.  The following array contians the percentage chance that a letter is picked in any list *B* based off of the 100,000 tests.

```
[A] => 30.213
[B] => 29.865
[C] => 30.357
[D] => 30.198
[E] => 30.152
[F] => 30.472
[G] => 30.343
[H] => 30.011
[I] => 51.367
[J] => 51.683
[K] => 30.271
[L] => 30.197
[M] => 30.341
[N] => 30.15
[O] => 30.225
[P] => 30.135
[Q] => 30.406
[R] => 30.083
[S] => 30.251
[T] => 30.369
[U] => 51.671
[V] => 52.098
[W] => 51.772
[X] => 51.739
[Y] => 51.891
[Z] => 93.74
```

When looking back at the algorithm this makes sense.  The algorithm incorrectly interpreted the original percentages to be the percentage chance that an object is picked for any given location, not any list *B*.  So for example, in reality, the chance that Z is picked in a list *B* is 93%, but the chance that Z is picked for an index *B<sub>n</sub>* is 20%.  This is NOT what I want.  I want the chance that Z is picked in a list *B* to be 20%.

Is this even possible?  How can it be done?

### EDIT 1

I tried simply having the sum of all *P<sub>i</sub>* = k, this worked if all *P<sub>i</sub>* are equal, but after modifying their values, it started to get more and more wrong.

Initial Probabilities

```
$list= [
    "A" => 8.4615,
    "B" => 68.4615,
    "C" => 13.4615,
    "D" => 63.4615,
    "E" => 18.4615,
    "F" => 58.4615,
    "G" => 23.4615,
    "H" => 53.4615,
    "I" => 28.4615,
    "J" => 48.4615,
    "K" => 33.4615,
    "L" => 43.4615,
    "M" => 38.4615,
    "N" => 38.4615,
    "O" => 38.4615,
    "P" => 38.4615,
    "Q" => 38.4615,
    "R" => 38.4615,
    "S" => 38.4615,
    "T" => 38.4615,
    "U" => 38.4615,
    "V" => 38.4615,
    "W" => 38.4615,
    "X" => 38.4615,
    "Y" =>38.4615,
    "Z" => 38.4615
];
```

Results after 10,000 runs

```
Array
(
    [A] => 10.324
    [B] => 59.298
    [C] => 15.902
    [D] => 56.299
    [E] => 21.16
    [F] => 53.621
    [G] => 25.907
    [H] => 50.163
    [I] => 30.932
    [J] => 47.114
    [K] => 35.344
    [L] => 43.175
    [M] => 39.141
    [N] => 39.127
    [O] => 39.346
    [P] => 39.364
    [Q] => 39.501
    [R] => 39.05
    [S] => 39.555
    [T] => 39.239
    [U] => 39.283
    [V] => 39.408
    [W] => 39.317
    [X] => 39.339
    [Y] => 39.569
    [Z] => 39.522
)
```